# How to pass an environment variable as a part of a command

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to run a jar which needs to be passed args value. How to pass an environment variable as args for the java in windows

Example:

```
Set OUT = hi

java -jar something.jar OUT
```

How to send this OUT an ideas??

Comment: There is a syntax problem with the `SET` command.  You have created a variable named `OUT{space}` and assigned it the value of `{space}hi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: What you asked for, use `%VARIABLE%` to access the variable (quote it to allow spaces)

```
java -jar something.jar "%OPT%"
```

Option 2: Read the environment variable **with** Java. And skip using the command line option

```
String outValue = System.getenv().get("OUT");
```